# Concat content of ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0

Trying to set the text inside progressBar and i am getting properly with Setters. but i have to concat this value with:

```
{TemplateBinding Value}+"% Completed
```

How do i concat with some other Text.

Code where text printed inside progressbar:

```
 <Border x:Name="whiteBorder" >
       <ContentPresenter   x:Name="perHolder" Content="{TemplateBinding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
 </Border>
```

Silverlight version 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [inline elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline.aspx), like runs:

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run Text="{TemplateBinding Value}"/>
   <Run Text="% Completed "/>
</TextBlock>
```

**EDIT:**

After looking at your example, I think you should not use content presenter in your template. Content presenter is for controls that can host content (Read:has a *content* property). Content presenter, when given a string as a content, will certainly display the string, and you may use it, but for strings your better bet is textblock. It also give oyu more control about how the string is displayed.

Also, my bad. TemplateBinding is picky about where it is available, and inline elements are out of his list. Your best bet is like Cris W. says, using stackpanel:

```
<Border x:Name="whiteBorder" >
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Value}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="% Completed"/>
     </StackPanel>/>
</Border>
```

Comment: I was just coming to add this to my answer after I thought about it a little later, haha beat me by 50mins, +1

Comment: Hi i got % completed but not TemplateBinding value with this.. if i use contentpresenter i can get.. can u please check what need to be changed or tell how i can make sure it works in this link..
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nro23mm0oecknk/Progress%20Bar.zip

Comment: If you're set on using ContentPresenter just combine the objects separately like <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"><ContentPresenter/><TextBlock Text="% Completed"/></StackPanel>

Answer (score 1):

Or... You could also just use `StringFormat`

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="perHolder" 
       Content="{TemplateBinding Value, StringFormat='\{\0}&#37; Completed'}" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This looks great i gave a try but did't work.. Please check this attached link i have made sample..
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nro23mm0oecknk/Progress%20Bar.zip
Please update it.

Comment: silverlight version 3.0

Comment: Ah crap I didn't see the version3 part. Which doesn't seem to support StringFormat which makes @sircodesalot 's answer the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

To augment values, use a class that implements an `IValueConverter`, which is described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

In essence, a class that implements `IValueConverter` will intercetpt the `value` in a method called `Convert`. The value you return from this method is the value you really want to display. Consider:

namespace Sharp {

```
    public class MyConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            // First cast the value to an 'int'.
            Int32 theInputtedValue = (Int32)value;

            // Then return the newly formatted string.
            return String.Format("{0}% Completed", theInputtedValue);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

}

Notice in the example above the value converter is in the namespace `Sharp`. Now we add this to the XAML definition:

```
<Window x:Class="Sharp.MyWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

         xmlns:lol="clr-namespace:Sharp">
```

The last line is the namespace where our value converter exists (that is, `lol` will now point to the `Sharp` CLR-namespace.

Next we add the class to our `Window` resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <lol:MyConverter x:Key="TheValueConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

this creates an instance of the class that you can use in the XAML. So, so far our XAML looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Sharp.MyWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

         xmlns:lol="clr-namespace:Sharp">

    <Window.Resources>
        <lol:MyConverter x:Key="TheValueConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

Now we simply add it to your content presenter like so:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Value, Converter={StaticResource TheValueConverter}}" ... />
```

This tells the `ContentPresenter` that when it goes to present the value, it should use the `TheValueConverter` instance, which is an instance of our `ValueConverter`. Two things to be careful of: (1) Make sure that you use the name of the *instance* (`TheValueConverter`) and not the *class* definition (`MyConverter`). (2) Make sure to wrap the instance name in `{StaticResource}`.

Comment: Please check this attached link i have uploaded sample.. dropbox.com/s/2nro23mm0oecknk/Progress%20Bar.zip Please update it